Try to hide some point in geometry node
I follow this yt tutorials https://youtu.be/RYCi4rdwbxo?si=88MuRk5xzsM8pnMJ.
in that its about make water along curve and its done. but I wanna try to hide some point I didnt want show it yet like here I try use instances but still confussing how to make it work together. so thanks! thats helpful to me for every answer!

You're already using the Curve factor for much of this GN tree, just use that, set a threshold below a certain value (determined by where you want them to appear) and use that to set the scale of the points to 0, or delete that geometry, or store the value in an attribute and use it in the shader, which will probably be much smoother.

Okay I will try. thanks!
